# dask cache delayed function example

Tags: caching, dask

A simple dask cache example.  Cache does not work as expected.  Let's assume we have a list of data and a series of delayed functions, expected that for a function that encounters the same input to cache/memoize the results according to cachey score.
This example demonstrates that is not the case.

```
import time
import dask
from dask.cache import Cache
from dask.diagnostics import visualize
from dask.diagnostics import Profiler, ResourceProfiler, CacheProfiler    

def slow_func(x):
    time.sleep(5)
    return x+1

output = []
data = np.ones((100))
for x in data:
    a = dask.delayed(slow_func)(x)
    output.append(a)
total = dask.delayed(sum)(output)

cache = Cache(2e9)
cache.register() 

with Profiler() as prof, ResourceProfiler(dt=0.25) as rprof,CacheProfiler() as cprof:
    total.compute()

visualize([prof, rprof, cprof])
```

[cache cprof plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U1O0.png)

After the initial parallel execution of the function would expect the next iteration upon calling the function with the same value to use a cache version. But obviously does not, dask_key_name is for designating the same output, but i want to assess this function for a variety of inputs and if seeing the same input use cached version.  We can tell if this is happening very easily with this function due to the 5 second delay and should see it execute roughly 5 seconds as soon as the first value is cached after execution.  This example executes every single function delayed 5 seconds.   I am able to create a memoized version using the cachey library directly but this should work using the dask.cache library.

Answer (score 0):

In dask.delayed you may need to specify the `pure=True` keyword.

You can verify that this worked because all of your dask delayed values will have the same key.

You don't need to use `Cache` for this if they are all in the same `dask.compute` call.